# HTML tag to redirect from mobile browser

Tags: html

In an HTML document, one can redirect to the native SMS application of any phone via the simple tag:

```
<a href="sms:+1234-222-333?body=Hello there"></a>
```

Is there any way to redirect to the **address book** of a phone via HTML?

Comment: to redirect to actually what? To some special contact? To create a new contact? What is the idea behind this?

Comment: To your phone's saved contact list, from where you can select a friend's phone number for instance. Precisely that.